# How to open encrypred USB flash drive in wine?

Tags: usb, wine, encryption

I have an encrypted Integral USB stick with LOCKV231.EXE

I was hoping that I may be able to use it in Kubuntu (12.4) through Wine, but when I right-click LOCKV231.EXE and select:
'Open with wine windows program loader'
I get a message saying:
"Please insert the device or run this utility as privileged user."

How can I load LOCKV231.EXE into wine with admin privileges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't unless you can find a linux clone of that software:

1. Wine doesn't support usb passthrough(or other device passthrough).
2. Wine has no concept of admin priviledges, so things written to assert running as admin fail.

You should be able to do it with virtualbox with usb passthrough and extensions for full highspeed usb support.

Comment: I'll have to learn about vitualbox, yet. Is there a possibility of starting up wine in admin mode?

Being new to Kubuntu, I am still thinking in XP terms, where I worked in a user account without rights. But if I needed to run a program as admin, I could just right-click it and select [ Run as... ] and enter the user and password.

Comment: Again, wine has no concept of admin privileges.  Read the answer.

Comment: No call for being rude. I have read and understood your answer. - - While my first question was if I could start an application in wine with admin privileges, my  second question was if I can run wine with admin privileges and than run an application in wine. - - I'm just looking at different angles of approaching a problem. - - Forget wine. Let me rephrase the question: How do I run any application in Kubuntu with administrator rights?

Comment: You don't run in wine with admin privileges.  You're not understanding the components to the question.  `sudo wine something` will almost certainly break your wine-prefix AND not get the application thinking it's running as admin.  Windows AS ADMIN on Linux without running a full copy of windows in virtualization is NOT POSSIBLE without patching the application.  The answer is still correct.